# Mockito can't mock any class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito

I want to mock a class that gets some data from a server for Android testing purposes when I detected that mockito doesn't mock my class:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.test.test.Data

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
```

This was a Kotlin class like this:

```
class Data {}
```

By default, Kotlin classes are final, so I added the open modifier but still got the same error.

I thought, that it was maybe because some of Data's properties are final classes, so I created this Kotlin class and tried to mock it:

```
open class Test {

    fun say() = "Not mocked"
}
```

When I got the same error again I created a Java class which is by default not final:

```
public class Test2 {

    public String say() { return "Not mocked (Java)"; }
}
```

These are the dependencies I use for mockito:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:5.4.0'
```

At this point, I don't understand its problems anymore.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please create a complete, minimal example which illustrates the problem. You haven't shown how you create mock or how you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, that mockito seems to be incompatible with Android buildTarget API 34, I changed it to 33 and it worked!